# Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've got a React component that makes a call to a backend API which returns an array of objects.
Essentially, I've got a `useFetch.js` file that fetches data and is then displayed in a `Products.js` file

My main issue is that when I simply log the data that is returned, no matter how many times I refresh my browser, the correct data is always logged. However, as soon as I include a map to render the data, it displays **only for the first time**, and then I get an error

> Cannot read property 'map' of null

The breakdown in the simple scenario when I just log the data:

**Products.js**

```
import React from "react";

import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import DisplayTable from "./DisplayTable"

export default function Products(props) {
    const [data, loading, error] = useFetch("http://localhost:8080/products");
    console.log("data", data)
    console.log("loading", loading)
    console.log("error", error)

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

**useFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useFetch(url) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    async function asyncFetchAPI() {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch(url, {method: "GET"})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data))
            .then(loading => setLoading(false))
            .catch((error) => {
                 console.log('error: ' + error)
                 setError(true)
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        asyncFetchAPI();
    }, []);

  return [data, loading, error];
}
```

The above works fine, and I can see the data in the console perfectly well. However, when I modify `Products.js` to include the map and display as follows

```
const displayTable = data.map(item => <DisplayTable key={item.id} item={item} />)
```

The new result is now:

```
import React from "react";

import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import DisplayTable from "./DisplayTable"

export default function Products(props) {
    const [data, loading, error] = useFetch("http://localhost:8080/products");
    console.log("data", data)
    console.log("loading", loading)
    console.log("error", error)

    const displayTable = data.map(item => <DisplayTable key={item.id} item={item} />)

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

At that point, I get

> Cannot read property 'map' of null

For what it's worth, my `DisplayTable.js` function looks like:

```
import React from "react"

function DisplayTable(props) {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <h1>{props.item.categoryId}</h1>
    )
}

export default DisplayTable
```

Comment: Try `data?.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by initializing your data state with empty array in your `useFetch.js` file

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

or in the other file i.e.

```
const [data = [], loading, error] = useFetch("http://localhost:8080/products");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are requesting data in an asynchronous manner right, so the first time, it is returned as `null`, then you try to map over `null`.
e.g. Here your data is `null` initially

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

`console.log` sometimes may show you the current state of variable, so don't get deceived by that.

So before mapping you can put a  condition something like:

```
data && data.map....
```

or use empty array as initial value

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I have just gone with the other answer because I decided not to initiate the state as null and include an empty array.